# Node.js how to use mongoose to do filter and pagination

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I get all data successfully in my node.js code using `Profile.find()`,but when I want to add filter in api, it get 500 error.

Profile.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

//Create Schema
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
    type: {
        type: String,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
    },
    cash:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
    
})

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model("profile",ProfileSchema);
```

api.js

```
const router = express.Router();
const Profile = require('../../models/Profile');

router.get("/",passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}),(req, res) => {
    Profile.find().then(profiles => {
        res.json(profiles)
    })//works
     
})
router.get("/",passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false}),(req, res) => {

    var condition = {'cash' : '5000'};
    Profile.find(condition,function(err,res){//error for this
        res.json(res)
    })
})
```

I am new to mongoose and do not sure how to do the filter and pagination for my code.
Appreciate for any kind help.

**Update**

Thanks to @Amila Senadheera, I finally find the solution to do filter and pagination using below code:

```
var condition = { cash: '5000' };
Profile.find(condition).skip(1).limit(10).then(profiles => { 
    res.json(profiles)
})
```

To use aggregation, it works like below:

```
router.post(
    "/",
    passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
      async (req, res) => {
        // page index
        let pageIndex = 1;
        // profiles per page
        let pageSize = 10;

        if (req.body.pageIndex !== null || req.body.pageIndex !== "undefined") {
            pageIndex = req.body.pageIndex;
        }

        if (req.body.pageSize !== null || req.body.pageSize !== "undefined") {
            pageSize = req.body.pageSize;
        }

        let condition = { description: "1" };
        try {
            const getAllProfile = await  Profile.aggregate([{
                $facet: {
                    data:[
                        { $match: condition },
                        { $skip: (pageIndex - 1) * pageSize },
                        { $limit: pageSize },
                       
                    ],
                    totalCount:[
                        { $match: condition },
                        { $count: 'totalCount' }
                    ]
                }
          
            }]) ; 
            res.json(getAllProfile);
        } catch (error) {
            res.status(404).json(error);
        }
      
    }
);
```

Comment: Why doesn't your `ProfileSchema` have `cash` as a field in the schema?

Comment: @Amila Senadheera Sorry,I forget to add that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [find](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find--) function can only accept `query` and `projection` as arguments. You are not allowed to give a callback as an argument. `then` should be chained to the `Promise` returned by `find`.

Try like this

```
var condition = {'cash' : '5000'};
Profile.find(condition).then(profiles => {
     res.json(profiles)
});
```

### Profiles with pagination.

you can use the MongoDB aggregation framework for that (which will make it possible to get additional information like the total entries and count of the entries on the current page (the last page might have a lesser number than the page limit)). You need to send `start` and `limit` as the request body.

```
router.get(
    "/",
    passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
    async (req, res) => {
        // page index
        let start = 0;
        // profiles per page
        let limit = 10;

        if (req.body.start !== null || req.body.start !== "undefined") {
            start = req.body.start;
        }

        if (req.body.limit !== null || req.body.limit !== "undefined") {
            limit = req.body.limit;
        }

        let condition = { cash: "5000" };

        try {
            const aggregatedData = await Profile.aggregate([
                {
                    $facet: {
                        data: [
                            { $match: condition },
                            {
                                $project: {
                                    type: 1,
                                    description: 1,
                                    cash: 1
                                }
                            },
                            { $skip: start * limit },
                            { $limit: limit }
                        ],
                        metaData: [
                            {
                                $group: {
                                    _id: null,
                                    count: { $sum: 1 }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]);
            return res.status(200).json({
                data: aggregatedData[0].data,
                metaData: {
                    total: aggregatedData[0].metaData[0].count,
                    start: start
                }
            });
        } catch (error) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                error: error
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: @Ryan, check this out !!

Comment: Ok， I will check,and how to do pagination in my code?

Comment: You can use mongodb aggregation framework to get the pagination work

Comment: Oh,I search for some articles and all they use as a callback, not know the reason but it works to use as Promise ,thank you

Comment: @Ryan, I have updated the answer on getting paginated profiles.

Comment: Thank you very much. I change a bit to return both pagination result and totalcounts based on your sample code and it works.Have a nice day!